# How do I set the HTTP User-Agent when using Search::Elasticsearch?

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I'm using [Search::Elasticsearch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Search::Elasticsearch) to query [MetaCPAN](https://github.com/CPAN-API/cpan-api/blob/master/docs/API-docs.md).

```
my $es = Search::Elasticsearch->new(
  cxn_pool => 'Static::NoPing',
  nodes    => 'api.metacpan.org:80',
);

my $scroller = $es->scroll_helper(
  index       => 'v0',
  type        => 'release',
  search_type => 'scan',
  scroll      => '2m',
  size        => $size,
  body        => {
    fields => [qw(author archive date)],
    query  => { range => { date => { gte => $date } } },
  },
);
```

This works ok, but I'd like to set the HTTP User-Agent header to a custom value so my requests can be identified if there's a problem.  How do I do that with Search::Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the `handle` constructor using [`handle_args`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Search::Elasticsearch::Role::Cxn#handle_args). So for the default [`HTTP::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) you would use `agent`:

```
my $es = Search::Elasticsearch->new(
  cxn_pool => 'Static::NoPing',
  nodes    => 'api.metacpan.org:80',
  handle_args => { agent => "youragent/0.1" },
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask if it's documented that you pass `handle_args` to `Search::Elasticsearch->new` and they get passed along to the `Cxn` object, but then I noticed that all the other configuration parameters defined in that role show an example of doing it that way.  I guess you're just supposed to assume that `handle_args` works the same way.